# How to add the datatable control elements from jquery.datatable.js to a dynamically created html table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, code-behind

I use a bootstrap template for my asp.net webforms project.  I copy and pasted the datatable section into my aspx page. After that I deleted the hardcoded table  ................

instead I created the table in the codebehind:

```
 Dim x3 As XmlElement = SearchService.FindAddressesBySearchtext(login, pass, Einschlitz.Text.ToString, False)


        Dim test As String = ConvertxmlToHTML(table1)

        datatableDIV.InnerHtml = test
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "table_function", "functiontest();", True)
```

As you see,  the variable test is placed placed into the

by   datatablediv.InnerHtml = test 
After that I call the functiontest() Javacscript Method shown at the end of the thread. 
here is the containter from my aspx page

```
<section class="content-header">
  <h1>
    Data Tables
    <small>advanced tables</small>
  </h1>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tables</a></li>
    <li class="active">Data tables</li>
  </ol>
</section>



           <!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">


      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Data Table With Full Features</h3>
        </div><!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body" id="datatablediv" runat="server">


        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
      </div><!-- /.box -->
    </div><!-- /.col -->
  </div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /.content -->
<!-- Main content -->
```

This is the function which gets called in the original template where the table is hardcoded,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $("#example1").dataTable();
        $('#example2').dataTable({
          "bPaginate": true,
          "bLengthChange": false,
          "bFilter": false,
          "bSort": true,
          "bInfo": true,
          "bAutoWidth": false
        });
      });
    </script>
```

I changed it to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
             function functiontest() {
                 alert('Function called successfully!');
                 $('#Datatable1').dataTable({
                     "bPaginate": true,
                     "bLengthChange": false,
                     "bFilter": false,
                     "bSort": true,
                     "bInfo": true,
                     "bAutoWidth": false
                 });

             }
           </script>
```

The html table I insert looks like exactly the same as the one which was hardcoded. But all the options like sorting the rows, searching for a special row in via a textbox, the pagination, all is missing. I don't know why, and I don't know how to add it correctly.

Comment: First thing!! Check for `console errors`!! Second thing have you referred `dataTable.js` file in your page??

Comment: Are you sure you have the ID set correctly? In your example, the ID of the DataTable is: `datatablediv`, while in the JavaScript code, you are using the ID: `Datatable1`

Comment: Yes the vars are correct. Datatable1 is the Id of the <table id="Datatable1">
DataTable.js is referred as scr. 
I checked the console errors and I got:
-getPreventDefault() should not be used anyore
-no element found
-no element found